# command \cite does not work

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I was using `biblatex` without so much trouble. But suddenly when I wanted to use `\cite`, no bibliography source appeared.
Here is a MWE:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,openright,10pt]{book}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=chem-angew,citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{biblio} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{titlesec}
 \usepackage{tocloft}
  \begin{document}
 \cite{debabrata_bhadra_synthesis_2011} % this reference actually does EXIST
  \end{document}
```

And then I copy the reference:

```
   @article{debabrata_bhadra_synthesis_2011,
title = {Synthesis of {PVDF}/{BiFeO}3 Nanocomposite and Observation of Enhanced Electrical Conductivity and Low-Loss Dielectric Permittivity at Percolation Threshold},
volume = {50},
doi = {10.1002/polb.23041},
pages = {572--579},
journaltitle = {{JOURNAL} {OF} {POLYMER} {SCIENCE} {PART} B: {POLYMER} {PHYSICS}},
shortjournal = {J. Polym. Sci., Part B: Polym. Phys.},
author = {{Debabrata Bhadra} and {Md. G. Masud} and {S. Sarkar} and {J. Sannigrahi} and {S. K. De} and {B. K. Chaudhuri}},
date = {2011-11-21},
file = {PVDF  BiFeO3 intro OK.pdf:C\:\\Users\\L-COM\\AppData\\Roaming\\Zotero\\Zotero\\Profiles\\wvijlgbz.default\\zotero\\storage\\I7SAEGPC\\PVDF  BiFeO3 intro OK.pdf:application/pdf}
}
```

This happens with all the references I have on the bibliography.
Here goes the error report:

```
  Data encoding is 'utf8'.
 No file tesis.bbl.
 Font shape `OT1/cmss/m/it' in size <10> not available(Font) Font shape            `OT1/cmss/m/sl' tried instead
   Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph
    Citation 'debabrata_bhadra_synthesis_2011' on page 3 undefined
Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph
Underfull \vbox (badness 1275) has occurred while \output is active []
Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph
  Overfull \hbox (129.53575pt too wide) in paragraph
`h' float specifier changed to `ht'.
  Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph
   Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph
    Overfull \hbox (15.0pt too wide) in paragraph
    Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph
    Empty bibliography
    There were undefined references.
   Please (re)run BibTeX on the file(s):(biblatex) tesis(biblatex) and rerun           LaTeX afterwards.
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: Your example works without any problems. Try deleting all the auxiliary files that are generated by LaTeX and BibTeX, maybe something bad is in one of them. By the way, you should add the file ending when giving the name of the bib for `\addbibresource`.

Comment: Your MWE works as expected. Delete all auxiliary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, ...) and try again. If you get any errors trying to compile report them here, have a very close look at the `.blg` file after the BibTeX run. Note that as Johannes says with `\addbibresource` you *must* give the file extension, if it works without that is just luck and not intended behaviour. Your `.bib` file is not fully optimised for `biblatex`: Giving the `journaltitle` in the way you do will give ALL-CAPS use `journaltitle = {Journal of Polymer Science Part B: Polymer Physics},` instead. ....

Comment: ... Your `author` field should read `author = {Debabrata Bhadra and Md. G. Masud and S. Sarkar and J. Sannigrahi and S. K. De and B. K. Chaudhuri},` so `biblatex` can tell apart the separate name parts.

Comment: @Johannes_B I tried deleting the file without success. I added the error report. thanks

Comment: So far, that shows just *relatively* harmless box warnings. Did you run BibTeX on your main.aux file again, followed by more latex runs?

Comment: @Johannes_B I tried but it doesn't work. Additionally, I got the following error after latex compiling "Windows API error 5: Denied Access". Could this have something to do with the \cite not working?

Comment: Hard to say, there are multiple issues here and the MWE in the question is meanwhile unrelated. I am not a Windows person, but sometimes everything chokes on Adobe Reader still having the pdf open.

Comment: Can you try to do the compilation from the command line and report the errors back here? Please try to compile the following really minimal example `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} 
\begin{document}
  \cite{sigfridsson}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}` (it should work without any changes, the `.bib` file `biblatex-examples.bib` comes with `biblatex` and should be found automatically).

Answer (score 5):

Some suggestions:

- add the instruction `\printbibliography` where the bibliography is supposed to be printed
- change `\addbibresource{biblio}` to `\addbibresource{biblio.bib}`
- remove the interior curly braces from the `author` and `journaltitle` fields
- be sure to run BibTeX and then LaTeX twice more.

With these changes, the one-item bibliography should look like this:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
@article{debabrata_bhadra_synthesis_2011,
title = {Synthesis of {PVDF}/{BiFeO}3 Nanocomposite and Observation of Enhanced Electrical Conductivity and Low-Loss Dielectric Permittivity at Percolation Threshold},
volume = {50},
doi = {10.1002/polb.23041},
pages = {572--579},
journaltitle = {JOURNAL OF POLYMER SCIENCE PART B: POLYMER PHYSICS},
shortjournal = {J. Polym. Sci., Part B: Polym. Phys.},
author = {Debabrata Bhadra and Md. G. Masud and S. Sarkar and J. Sannigrahi and S. K. De and B. K. Chaudhuri},
date = {2011-11-21},
file = {PVDF  BiFeO3 intro OK.pdf:C\:\\Users\\L-COM\\AppData\\Roaming\\Zotero\\Zotero\\Profiles\\wvijlgbz.default\\zotero\\storage\\I7SAEGPC\\PVDF  BiFeO3 intro OK.pdf:application/pdf},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper,openright,10pt]{book}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
 \usepackage{setspace}
 \usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=chem-angew,citestyle=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
 \addbibresource{biblio.bib} 
 \usepackage{csquotes}
 \usepackage{titlesec}
 \usepackage{tocloft}

\begin{document}
\cite{debabrata_bhadra_synthesis_2011} % this reference actually does EXIST
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```